# Mostrar una variable en un input de html

Tags: php, html5

buenas tardes hoy acudo a ustedes debido a que necesito mostrar una variable (que es enviada por la url) en un input text, mi codigo para mostrar es el siguiente:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" name="cedula" class="form-control" placeholder="Cédula" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" value="<?php echo $cedula; ?>">
```

el problema es que en vez de mostrar el contenido de la variable lo que me muestra en el input es la parte del php.

```
<?php echo $cedula; ?
```

no se cual es el error

el codigo que envia el parametro es el siguiente:

```
<a href="{{URL}}/register/?cedula=321" class="link register">¿No estoy registrado? Regístrarme ahora</a>
```

capturo el valor de la cedula asi:

```
<?php $cedula = $_REQUEST['cedula'];?>
```

Comment: El primer trozo de código tiene sintaxis válida, pero falta contexto. Asignar variables a $_REQUEST no es una buena práctica. Podrías editar tu pregunta, añadiendo un código replicable donde se le haga un print / echo a $cedula para ver qué valor se está almacenando ahí?

Answer (score 0):

No olvides que $_REQUEST es diferente a $_GET o $_POST por ende debes obtener la variable por url $_GET

```
<?php $cedula = $_GET['cedula'];?>
<input type="text" maxlength="10" name="cedula" class="form-control" placeholder="Cédula" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" value="<?php echo $cedula; ?>">
```

**Verifica que la extension del archivo sea .php y no .html**

Comment: ya he probado con GET pero sigue mostrando en el input :<?php echo $cedula; ?>

Comment: Y la extensión del archivo es la correcta?

Answer (score 0):

Tengo la ligera sospecha que este codigo lo estas usando en un archivo .html
porque al ser php no tienes no te deberia mostrar codigo php
por mas que estes llamando a variables no definidas o inexistentes simplemente te deberia apareces nada (null)

**Solucion: verifica que tu archivo no sea html si no .php**

Answer (score -1):

Tenes que capturar la variable primero

```
$dato = $_GET['cedula']
echo $dato
```

Comment: si lo estoy capturando me faltó agregar eso en la pregunta, lo capturo así:       
 <?php $cedula = $_REQUEST['cedula'] ?>

Comment: Esa “captura” es innecesaria y duplica la cantidad de memoria requerida.